# New computer sends extra keystrokes

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, drivers

I've just bought a new Asus eee pc 1225b. The problem is that when the computer is starting to get hot, or warmed up, some keystrokes are sent to the computer even though I don't press them on the keyboard. This problem/bugg usually takes place when I press multiple keys, especially with <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. When i press the key combination, a bunch of other keys are registered too, usually `öo-ly,.`. This is very weird since to computer is brand new. Is this some problem with the drivers, according to windows 7 they are up to date, or do you think it sounds like a hardware fault and that I should return the computer? I don't experience this problem when I use an external keyboard, only when using the built-in one.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me. Why not try another OS (e.g. Ubuntu) to see if the same problem occurs? That way you should be able to rule out some sort of software issue.

Comment: The fact this doesn't happen when you use an external keyboard, indicates without a doubt, you have a hardware problem.  If the device is new, I would send it under warrenty, for repair.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just hope that my reseller's support will become a bit more helpful, so far I haven't been able to get in contact with them, But I will try again tomorrow.